# Is there a way to get log information showing when dyno changes were made?

Tags: heroku, datadog

We are currently altering our Heroku dynos and then monitoring to see the impact of the changes. This is so we can optimise what we're using. I can't find anywhere in the logs that shows the date/time/person who changed the dyno settings.

Current workaround: in a spreadsheet I make a note of the date/time and the change made. In Datadog, when reviewing my graphs of dyno load and memory usage, I try to roughly estimate visually where the change was made.

What I'm trying to do: in Datadog I would like to add an overlay event that flags or tags the date/time of the heroku dyno change on the graph so that we can more easily see before/after the change, and also so we have an audit record of changes made.

I've read through all the support docs and can't seem to find anything obvious that will give me the audit information, and it doesn't appear to be present in any of the logs we have in Datadog.

If someone could either point me in the right direction, or better yet, provide some steps that I can pass on to one of my engineers, that would really help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to track changes to your dynos is to implement the [dyno event webhook](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/webhook-dyno-events). Then you can write all of the changes to logs of your choosing, and then send them to Datadog as you would any other log.

Comment: Thanks @bwest - I'll ask the devs to implement that for me